# Higher overlay modes on Freescale i.MX 6 Dual

Tags: linux, video, embedded

I am playing 1080p video on Freescale i.MX 6's IPU 0 Display 0 Background DI (/dev/video16) and want to overlay it with Qt application via Overlay DI (/dev/fb1). It works really great, but only in small part of the screen because the only video mode available for /dev/fb1 is 240x320p-60:

```
root@box:~# cat /sys/class/graphics/fb1/modes   
U:240x320p-60
```

Can it be higher and how?

Comment: Just in case its relevant... what distro does that use?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek any distro that hardware vendor ships. We have Ubuntu 12.04 for Utilite and Debian testing / Ubuntu 11.10 for Hummingboard... Both are having the same issues.

Comment: Have you tried using the Linux Ubuntu installation from Freescale? http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX6D&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab Go to the Board Support packages under Runtime Support and there should be a roots for Linux.